# can I disable rollback in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Today I lost about 6 hours of work because I did 'hg rollback' instead of 'hg revert'. I won't waste time talking about how dumb it is to have a destructive command that has no confirmation or warning.

I'd prefer to make it so that I can't make a simple mistake like that again. Is there a way I can disable this command from the command line?

Comment: Note that `hg rollback` does not alter the working directory - so if you accidentally `rollback`, you can re-commit the existing working directory to recover the commit.

Comment: @Amber true, and I would have done that, except I thought I had done a revert and my repo was fine. I then merged in code with a pull/merge. I don't know exactly what happened, just that the extensive refactoring I did this morning is gone.

Comment: It is a great case that when you do something wrong - you need to stop and think carefully about what happened and how to fix it, not try everything randomly

Comment: @jcollum: I recently discovered that a merge performed by `hg update` does **not** loose work either.  If you mess up your working copy like that you can always use `hg resolve`.

Comment: @zerkms a) you're being a bit condescending here b) your advice works fine, if you realize you do something wrong -- in this case mercurial gives no warning that it did anything out of the ordinary and I went happily on with my work

Comment: @jcollum: after `hg rollback` I see the message that states that the last commit has been rolled back. So "in this case mercurial gives no warning" - this is just not true

Comment: @zerkms to me a warning is "This command cannot be undone!" not "Ok I did what you asked me to do". The latter is what I got. The former is what should be shown.

Comment: @zerkms also a warning happens before something bad happens.

Comment: @jcollum: oh, so if it is not written explicitly that "you cannot dry your cat in this microwave" - you would do that? You asked a rollback, and you got `repository tip rolled back to revision -1 (undo commit)`. This is not what you generally would like to see for correct `revert`, as long as you know that `revert` doesn't modify history.

Comment: @jcollum: it is not bad. It doesn't do anything that cannot be fixed. It doesn't delete your data.

Comment: @zerkms Quote: that "you cannot dry your cat in this microwave" -- now you're being rude. I'm not discussing this further with you.

Comment: @jcollum: as you wish, but it doesn't change the fact that mercurial warned you, but you didn't read the message and blame it after, that it didn't warn you with more "obvious" message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can clobber it with an alias.  Try adding the following to your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
rollback = !echo WAT?
```

Note that it may not work properly with old mercurial versions (I would say, older than 1.8).

Comment: Thanks. Now I get `PS C:\dev\TestRep> hg rollback`
`WAT?`. The last commit was not removed. Looks good.